# Logging and writing error messages to a dataframe

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

I intend to record the errors in my R code while calling functions in a dataframe (ERR_LOG, say). I want to use 'try' to identify errors while calling a function,if any.The dataframe(ERR_LOG) will have the following columns :

1. Time : The time at which the function was called (Sys.time)
2. Loc : For which function call was this error recorded (name of the
   function)
3. Desc : Description of the error which R throws at us (Error message
   in R)

Example :

First I would like to initialize a blank dataframe 'ERR_LOG' with these columns

Then write the function

```
f <- function(a){
  x <- a*100
  return(x)
}
```

Now I put the output of the call to 'f' in 'chk'

```
chk <- try(f())
```

The above call gives the error 'Error in a * 100 : 'a' is missing' (description of the error)

Check

```
if(inherits(chk,'try-error'))

{then I want to populate ERR_LOG and stop the code execution}
```

How can this be done in R?

Comment: For one, you're getting an error on the call `f()`, because you defined it to accept an argument `a`, but call it without passing any values.

Comment: @voidHead I know this will thriw an error.. but this is just an example to explain what I intend to do

Answer (score 1):

use `tryCatch` instead of `try`

Then inside `tryCatch()`, use the argument `error=function(e){}`

`e` will have an element named message, which is what you would like

Use the following call with browser to explore `e$message`:

```
x <- tryCatch(stop("This is your error message"), error=function(e) {browser()})
```

---

Note that your function need not be anonymous.

```
MyErrorParser <- function(e) {
  m <- e$message
  if (grepl("something", m))
     do something
  return (something_else)
}

## THEN
tryCatch(stop("This is a test"), error=MyErrorParser)
```

Comment: Could you please explain how to create the dataframe required and insert the data into that?